# Cloning a UDP packet recieved on localhost to another IP

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking, udp

I have a `machine A` with local ip `192.168.0.199` - I want to clone all udp packets recieved on a local machine and forward to machine A

i tried the below in IP tables

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -t nat -p udp -s 127.0.0.1 --dport 32000 -j TEE --gateway 192.168.0.199
```

on `machine A` - i start listening for UDP packets with `netcat -l -u -p 32000`

and on my local machine - i send a test udp packet

```
echo 'ved' | nc -u 127.0.0.1 32000
```

the packet seems to reach my local instance port but i cant seem to recieve the cloned packet on `machine A` -

Is there something else i need to be doing?

**EDIT** - so if i do a `tcpdump` on `machine A` - packets do seem to be arriving on the port - but not sure why this isnt captured by netcat - i tried listening on all interfaces as well

`sudo tcpdump -n udp port 32000 -e`

[image]

does seem to show incoming packets - but why isnt this captured by netcat

Could this have something to do with the source IP not being changed? tcpdump still shows 127.0.0.1 as the source IP

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the problem was that the packets were getting dropped in `machine A` because the destination IP doesnt get changed by the TEE module

So  in `Machine A`s IP table - i had to run this
`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 32000 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.0.199`